# Take screenshot

Tags: android, android-emulator

How to take screenshot using android emulator?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Open the Devices view in Eclipse (Window -> Show View -> Other, Android -> Devices), and there's a toolbar button on the right side labeled "Screen Capture":

[image: Screenshot of Eclipse]

Comment: am getting a blue cross image in my mac... :(

Comment: re: the blue cross image. Make sure you have the actual device selected like the screen-shot shows. I was having the same issue until I realized there was nothing selected for a screen grab.